# Oracle 10g Administration

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-10g

Redo log files are not multiplexed in our database. Redo log blocks are corrupted in group 2, and archiving has stopped. All the redo logs are filled and database activity is halted. Database writer has written everything to disk. Which command would execute to proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you did not lose any data and the problem is only at redolog level you can issue (as sysdba):

```
alter database open resetlogs;
```

backup all the datafiles, control files and online redo log before issuing the command  so you can "rollback" if something goes wrong.